# How to print a line to terminal before System.exit(0)? Synchronization issue

Tags: java, synchronization, system.out

The goal is to print some message to terminal before calling `System.exit(0);` like:

```
System.out.println("Stopping the server...");
System.exit(0);
```

But application exits before the message is printed. How to synchronize it? Using Java JDK8 SE.

Comment: did you try to [flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush())?

Comment: are you using JEE or Spring or what

Comment: Yes, `System.out.flush()` was the answer, thanks! :)

Comment: did you tried [@PreDestroy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must [flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush()) the stream before you exit the application.

```
System.out.println("Stopping the server...");
System.out.flush();
System.exit(0);
```